# Match and extract substrings inside double quotes with regex

Tags: python, regex, match

I have a list of strings like this `data = ['This is the sentence "Hello" by writer "MK"', '2 Worlds [Harry]']`

and I want to extract only the `"Hello`, here's what I did:

```
import re
s = re.match('This is the sentence (.*) by writer', data[0])
s
```

But instead of `"Hello`, I got this `<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 38), match='This is the sentence "Hello" by writer'>`

Can someone tell me how to write it correctly?

Comment: Are you trying to achieve something like this? https://eval.in/867424

Comment: when you print `s`, it prints the regex Match object - much in the same way that if you write a function, then print the function's name without calling it, you'll get the string representation of that object, *not* what the function would return.  If you want to access the group you signified with `(.*)`, you'd have to access that explicity: `print(s.group(1))`

Comment: The solution you marked is suboptimal in terms of the regex. If you want to improve your regex, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46398384/4909087

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you print s, it prints the regex Match object - much in the same way that if you write a function, then print the function's name without calling it, you'll get the string representation of that function, not what the function would return:

```
def hello():
    return 'hello!'

print(hello)
>>> <function hello at 0x7f570e3aa9b0>
```

If you want to access the group you signified with (.*), you'd have to access that explicitly:

```
s = re.match('This is the sentence (.*) by writer', data[0])
print(s.group(1))
>>>"Hello
```

Additionally, you can check if there's a matching group the following way, avoiding an AttributeError if there wasn't a match:

```
 s = re.match('This is the sentence (.*) by writer', data[0])
 if s:
     print(s.group(1))
```

Comment: With every edit, this answer is getting closer to mine... would appreciate some attribution or just not adding it at all, thanks.

Comment: what do you want attribution for? My comment, which is essentially the same as this answer, was posted 2 minutes before your answer.

Comment: The part mentioning the AttributeError. A simple, "As coldspeed mentions in their answer, you can check..." would suffice.

Comment: i'll pass - wasn't even looking at your answer when i added that in

Comment: It's easy to say that, but the fact remains that it is a lot like my answer and it was added in after I added mine, so you can understand where I'm coming from :)

Comment: one could argue that your answer is essentially the same as my comment so, again, i'll pass

Comment: I don't know about you, but I don't think that's even a point up for discussion.

Comment: No, thank you. I've said all I have to. I won't downvote because your answer isn't wrong, but I also won't upvote posts that clearly borrow from other answers without any attribution.

Answer (score 0):

're.match' returns a 'MatchObject', you need to do use `.group(1)` to get the data from the match.